What systems/subsystems does statistical mechanics actually apply to?
I've been trying to start learning statistical mechanics but I've run into a few roadblocks with the terminology being used and need clarification before I continue. Specifically, I want to clarify what systems and subsystems really are, at least ones that admits a description by the laws of statistical mechanics. I understand that the term system is used in a variety of subfields but it seems as if most texts are very lenient with the definitions of systems and subsystems--the extent to which they're defined is usually the number of particles they constitute. But this leaves me somewhat confused.
Subsystems:
For example, in Landau and Lifshitz statistical mechanics book, they define subsystems as "A part of the system which is very small compared with the whole system but still macroscopic". This feels a little lenient. Do the particles need to be confined at all? Can they be randomly selected? For example, can we classify both a small fluid parcel of water in a still water bottle and, say, any 1% of the particles in a sample of highly pressurized gas to be subsystems? For the gas example, the idea of the particles not staying confined to a specific, localized area (unlike the fluid parcel) somewhat bothers me which is why I feel weird considering it as a subsystem. Further, it doesn't seem obvious that it ever reaches equilibrium. As for the water example, it seems like over a short period of time, maybe it would behave like a confined system in equilibrium. However, it seems like after a short period of time a few particles would escape and the system would no longer be in equilibrium.
Systems:
Regarding systems, most of my knowledge of statistical mechanics comes from poorly taught chemistry courses. So I am used to thinking of a system as a fluid or gas enclosed in a container. But this definition seems to not require a container. However, if I'm not mistaken, a system must be confined to some fixed finite volume at any instant if it is to read equilibrium (assuming the system itself is finite). It also seems to imply we can describe materials like solids which I have never heard of, which leaves me uncertain. I'm having trouble wording my concerns so I will leave it at the question: are there any examples of systems in which all the (many) particles are in a bound state (i.e. stay confined in some volume which may not be enclosed by walls) and can not be described by statistical mechanics? Or is it usually safe to assume as long as the particles aren't freely flying around in some unconfined space that it will be able to be described by statistical mechanics.
In section 2 of L&L they somewhat discuss what I am asking (particularly regarding subsystems) but it doesn't specifically address my concerns. They seem to describe a case where the subsystems ARE locally confined (like the fluid parcel) and can't move very far in a short period of time (like a bead of dye slowly diffusing into water as opposed to, say, a small sample of gas in a container). However these seem to only cover a limited amount of situations--I dont really even see it applying well to gasses so I am unsure if I am missing the bigger picture.

Using L&L as a primary learning text is going to be needlessly painful. Get something like Reif or some other commonly used university textbook.

@JonCuster while they might not be the best at explaining I find that they do the best job at making sure no boxes are left unchecked. I really want to make sure I get the fundamentals down and after skimming a few other texts I am doubting I will find anything better for this purpose

Look, I love various L&L texts, but verbose explanations are not their style. They are great for a review that hits everything with brevity. I always used other books alongside them to clarify points.
